# Is there a way to get function decorator metadata by nest provider?

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, nestjs, decorator

I've been writing a nestjs module to watch my queues and exchanges on rabbitmq, currently to implement the library functionalities you have to register your exchanges at the RankMyRabbitmqModule and then match it in your Watch decorator like in the example below:

Module:

```js
RankMyRabbitmqModule.forRootAsync({
      urls: ['amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672'],
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: 'ex01',
          type: 'direct',
        },
        {
          name: 'ex02',
          type: 'direct',
        },
      ],
    }),
```

Watch decorator:

```js
@Watch({
    queue: 'q1',
    exchange: 'ex01',
    routingKey: 'blue',
  })
  blue(msg) {
    console.log('[BLUE]:', msg);
  }
```

It will just watch my queue and set the function to execute the things inside there using the params, But I was thinking about a way to improve this library and I want to have a structure like this

```js
@Exchange('ex01')
@Injectable()
export class Exchange01 {
  @ExchangeRoute({
    routingKey: 'blue',
    queue: 'q1'
  })
  blue(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  }

  @ExchangeRoute({
    routingKey: 'red',
    queue: 'q1'
  })
  red(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  }
}
```

To do it I have to get the provider metadata first and then get its method metadata as well... Is there a way to get metadata in this way ? This is my current implementation to get just a decorator metadata

```js
@Module({})
class MyModule implements OnModuleInit{
  async OnModuleInit() {
    const discoveryMethods = await params.discovery.providerMethodsWithMetaAtKey(META_KEY);

  //TODO
  //Get Provider By MetaKey
  //Get Providers methods metadata
  }

}
```

Obs: I'm using a library called @golevelup/nestjs-discovery to get the methods metadata.

If there is a way to get my provider by metadata and then get my provider methods metadata it will help me a lot to implement this new feature, someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I find out a way to do it using the same library, Now I can get the methods metadata using these methods bellow

```js
const discoveredClasses = await this.discovery.providersWithMetaAtKey(
      decoratorKey,
    );

    for (const { discoveredClass, meta } of discoveredClasses) {
      const queueMeta = this.discovery.classMethodsWithMetaAtKey(
        discoveredClass,
        QUEUE_KEY,
      );

      console.log(queueMeta);
    }
```

- The first one is discovery.providersWithMetaAtKey which will give me all providers with my target metakey
- The second one is discovery.classMethodsWithMetaAtKey which will give me my method metadata based on the "discoveredClass" that is a type of object provided by the library @golevelup/nestjs-discovery